# Menu hidden links and bots!

Tags: seo, links, web-crawlers, menu, cloaking

I want to make a menu with a list with hidden links and when the user points the menu with he mouse the links will appear, my problem is that the bots may think this as a deceiving tactic and lower my page's rank.

How can stop bots from seeing this links? I found the rel="nofollow" attribute but i don't know if it working with all bots!

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, I probably misunderstood the term hidden links! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a simple show-hide javascript example. If he user has the capability os make the links to show up, then it would not be classifyed as an attempt to fool the engines. That's nothong wrong with that. About nofollow, take a Look at Matt's blog: http://www.google.com.br/search?q=matt+cutts+nofollow

Answer (score 1):

Don't nofollow those links. That would hurt your site, not help it. Hiding links the way you have described is perfectly fine. The only time hiding something is bad is when you are only hiding it to manipulate the search engines. This is called cloaking. You are not cloaking. So literally don't worry about it at all.